# How do add a file to directory without modifying the directory's modify timestamp?

Tags: unix, copy, filesystems, timestamp

Is there a way to copy a file into a directory while preserving this directory's timestamps?

Comment: An approach (if possible) would be to not depend on the file system's timestamps but on explicit timestamps you include in the folder name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A directory is pretty much literally just a file that lists the names/inodes of the files stored within it. Adding a new file to a directory, or even just renaming a file, requires re-writing the directory file itself to update the information. As such, changing adding/removing/renaming a file in a directory will also update the directory's own timestamps.

Comment: Hmm, then I'll have to manually adjust these attributes. I suppose I could save the directory's mtime, copy the file, and reset it to the original rght?

Comment: yes. but be aware that this can break things like backups. If a directory's timestamp doesn't change, then tar (and other apps) can assume that nothing has changed in the dir and will miss any of the changes you've made.

Comment: Thanks, yeah in my case the app in question is incorrectly assuming there are changes and I need to change its mind :).